# With Eclipse, in a PHP project with SVN, how to "tell" Eclipse to find autocompletion choice only in the current trunk or branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, autocomplete

Using Eclipse on a PHP Project, I recently created a tag on my SVN. Since that day, let's say I'm working on a class in my trunk, when I ctrl+space in my code, Eclipse is getting really really slow (sometimes even freeze), and if I'm lucky, it will give me 2 responses for autocompletion : One referencing some method/class from the tag, one referencing method/class from the trunk. But right now, only the reference from the trunk would be useful for me.

Is there a way to limit where Eclipse parse the code to give back autocompletion suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you have both versions of the project open in the workspace. Close one of them and it should work as expected.

I'd be really surprised if Eclipse would checkout a different version of your code from SVN for autocompletion.

Comment: Well, I got one Eclipse project open, with at its root directory (in the php explorer) the branches/tags/trunk directories, so yeah, everything is "virtually open".
You suggest that I should have 1 eclipse project = trunk, 1 other eclipse project = tag #1, and so on ? I'm not too familiar with quite confusing-easy-to-get-lost Eclipse's config and workspace things :)

Comment: No, I assume that you have more than one project open *or* that your project contains several copies of the source code. For example, you checked out the Subversion root (which contains trunk/ and branches/) instead of the trunk alone. Open the "Progress View" (Menu Window -> Show View -> Progress) and the "SVN console" (Click on the little arrow down in the Console and select "SVN Console"). Try to complete something and check whether either of them shows something.